# Adding [SoapHeader()] to a web method breaks reflection

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

In my ASPX site I've added a WebService class which is going to be called by another tool via SOAP.  If I add the SoapHeader attribute to the method, then the tool is getting a reflection error back:

`SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Method SupportedSites.HelloWorld can not be reflected`

Is there another attirbute I need to put on there?

Comment: What does your WebService class currently look like?

Comment: I refuse to answer that question on the grounds it'll make me look like a dork :)  I figured out what I was doing wrong.  RTFM more....